# Using Autofac Registration middleware to resolve a version of the service

Tags: c#, autofac, middleware

I want to resolve the Named registration where the name is given at runtime.

Background story - I am exposing my endpoints with multiple versions, e.g.:

```
https://localhost/myservice/api/v1/allcities
https://localhost/myservice/api/v2/allcities
...
```

The controller needs to invoke a different version of the injected service based on the version of the invoked endpoint.

To illustrate, I would expect when I invoke `https://localhost/myservice/api/v1/blahblah` it executes using `MyServiceV1` and when I invoke `https://localhost/myservice/api/v2/blahblah` it executes using  `MyServiceV2`

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 API with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning`, Autofac 6.

I can get what version was invoked via `IHttpContextAccessor` as `contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion()`.
In this question I want to focus on resolving a specific version of the service at runtime.

My idea was to register the service as `Named` (or Keyed, doesn't matter) and using the Registration middleware registration intercept the resolution process and inject the proper version of the Named service.

Code:

```cs
public interface IMyService 
{ 
   string GetImplementationVersion();
} 

[MyServiceVersioning("1.0")]
public class MyService1 : IMyService
{
    public string GetImplementationVersion() => "Example 1.0";
}

[MyServiceVersioning("2.0")]
public class MyService2 : IMyService
{
    public string GetImplementationVersion() => "Example 2.0";
}

public class MyMasterService
{
    private IMyService _myService;
    public MyMasterService(IMyService myService)
    {
       _myService = myService;
    }

    public string GetInjectedVersion() => _myService.GetImplementationVersion();
}
```

The registrations (**Edited** for completeness)

```cs
// ... 
builder.RegisterType<VersionService>().As<IVersionService>();
// next two lines registered using extension that's in the next code block example
builder.RegisterVersioned<MyServiceV1, IMyService>(); 
builder.RegisterVersioned<MyServiceV2, IMyService>();
builder.Register<MyMasterService>();
```

And finally the implementation of `RegisterVersioned` extension where the question lies:

```cs
public static class AutofacVersioningExtensions
{
public static IRegistrationBuilder<T, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>
            RegisterVersioned<T, TInterface>(this ContainerBuilder builder) where T: class
        {
            var versioningAttribute = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<MyServiceVersionAttribute>();
            if (versioningAttribute == null)
            {
                // no versioning exists, do it simply
                return builder.RegisterType<T>().As<TInterface>();
            }
            
            return builder.RegisterType<T>().As<TInterface>().Named<TInterface>(versioningAttribute.Version).ConfigurePipeline(p =>
            {
                p.Use(PipelinePhase.RegistrationPipelineStart, (context, next) =>
                {
                    var invokedVersion = context.Resolve<IVersionService>().CurrentVersion;
// HERE --> in the next line issue is that we have obvious circular resolution
// + it only resolves the last registration
// (I could do Resolve<IEnumerable<TInterface>> to get all registrations but that's an overhead that I'd like to avoid if possible).

                    var resolved = context.ResolveNamed<TInterface>(invokedVersion); 
                    if (resolved != null)
                    {
                        context.Instance = resolved;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        next(context);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
}
```

Do you have any ideas? Is my approach even on the right path?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the [key filtering attribute](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html#keyfilterattribute)?

Comment: I need it to be dynamic i.e. at runtime - based on the invoked API, I want to inject one version of the service or the other

Comment: Gotcha. I read that but I guess I didn't quite get it at first. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of what's getting resolved and _how_ that gets resolved? Also how you determine which service was invoked? I assume the thing getting resolved is `MyMasterService`, but I don't see that getting registered.

Comment: I updated the question for completeness - I hope it helps, it should be more complete now. 
In short - the thing I'm resolving is `MyMasterService`, it has DI with `IMyService` that has two implemented versions - `MyServiceV1` and `MyServiceV2`. Which exactly gets resolved is something that should be given with `IVersionService.CurrentVersion` (IVersionService works ok, I can get runtime version without issues). What I don't know is how to get specific registered version of `IMyService` that matches that version at runtime.

Comment: @TravisIllig
I guess if `KeyFilter` would accept a lambda for resolving the actual key value it would resolve this issue. E.g. `[KeyFilter(ctx => ctx.Resolve<IVersionService>().CurentVersion)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could make this easier by using a lambda registration.

```cs
builder.RegisterType<MyServiceV1>().Keyed<IMyService>("1.0");
builder.RegisterType<MyServiceV2>().Keyed<IMyService>("2.0");
builder.Register<MyMasterService>();
builder.Register(ctx =>
{
  var version = ctx.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion();
  return ctx.ResolveKeyed<IMyService>(version);
}).As<IMyService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This way, when you resolve an un-keyed `IMyService`, it'll go through the detection process and return the right keyed version. That keyed instance will be cached for the duration of the request.

Comment: That's amazingly simple, thanks!  But now I'm thinking how can I scale this so I can put the version on any service? The downside to this proposed solution is that I have to remember to re-register every interface that has multiple versions at the end of the builder registrations. (i.e. it would be great if we could just put the versioning attribute on a service and it just works)

Comment: You could use [assembly scanning](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html) or even your own reflection to interrogate your assemblies and execute registrations dynamically. I think you can probably figure out from the docs and other examples out there how to do that, it shouldn't be terribly difficult.